# I'm not the DBA, but I own the schema, and want to view the users assigned to a role

Tags: oracle, roles

I am not a DBA, but I own a schema which hundreds of people access.  For convenience, I created some roles, and assigned users to them.  Since I own the schema and created the role, I feel like I should be able to quickly list all of the people in that role. Since I'm not the dba, I can't do:

```
SELECT * FROM DBA_ROLE_PRIVS;
```

The only way I can verify that I added users to the role is for me to check the orginal script I used to add users to the role. Am I missing something? I can list all of the objects the role has access to via:

```
SELECT * FROM role_tab_privs
WHERE OWNER = '<me>';
```

But I just can't see who gets to see those objects.

Thanks for any assistance!
Mike

Answer (score 1):

You can try `USER_SYS_PRIVS`, `USER_TAB_PRIVS`, `USER_ROLE_PRIVS`

`... where ROLE = 'whatever';`

More info, and non-DBA views: [here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B10501_01/server.920/a96521/privs.htm#15665)